# VisualFlow dynamic choice not displaying any record after deployment to production

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, visual-flows

I have created a VisuaFlow where the user starts off from a screen where they have a picklist to select all created Pricebooks.

When created and tested in Sandbox environment, the picklist correctly shows all created Pricebooks. But when deployed to production the picklist cannot show the Pricebooks.

Is there some security setting I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you need to assign all the field level security of pricebooks object, it must be private thats the reason you cant the result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could definitely be security settings. Are you trying when logged in as a system administrator, or as a user? I would also suggest posting the criteria you are using for the pricebooks dynamic lookup. It could be that you are querying using a recordtype id or something else that is environment-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Matt and Maruf, it turned out to be field level security. 
One of the custom fields was set to Field Access = Hidden.

Some extra detail for others who view this:

1. In the custom fields, I clicked into the Custom Field Definition Detail > View Field Accessibility.
2. Set the Field Access to something other than Hidden.
3. Check the flow - the pricebook objects are displayed now.